# Redirect after the flash message disappears in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-flashmessages

I have a function which calls a service.

```
submitPost(value:any)
{    
    this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
          data => {
                this.responseStatus = data;
                if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
                {
                  localStorage.setItem('admin_id', this.responseStatus.detail.id);
                  this._flashMessagesService.show(this.responseStatus.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
                  top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard';
                }
                else
                {
                  this._flashMessagesService.show(this.responseStatus.message, { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 2000 });
                }
              },
          err => {
                console.log(err)
              },
          () => {}
      ); 
      this.status = true;       
}
```

My concern is with this section of code:-

```
if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
{
    localStorage.setItem('admin_id', this.responseStatus.detail.id);
    this._flashMessagesService.show(this.responseStatus.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
    top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard';
}
```

Is there any way by which the redirect action could take place after the flash message disappears after 5000 ms? Something like this:-

```
if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
{
    localStorage.setItem('admin_id', this.responseStatus.detail.id);
    this._flashMessagesService.show(this.responseStatus.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: {function(){ top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard'; }, 5000 });
}
```

Comment: You have your timeout, so you know how long your message is gonna be displayed. Why don't you do a setTimeout to navigate after that many milliseconds? Probably if timeout is 5000, do a redirect after 6000 or 7000 ms using setTimeout

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But I want it to do when the flash message disappears. Something like a callback.

Comment: So your flashMessage will dissappear after 5000 ms, that is 5 seconds. That is why you pass a timeout parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should navigate after the message disappears. Yout flashMessage will be displayed for 5000 ms and your navigate should happen after 7000ms

```
if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
{
    localStorage.setItem('admin_id', this.responseStatus.detail.id);
    this._flashMessagesService.show(this.responseStatus.message, { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
    setTimeout(()=>{
      top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard';
    },7000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by having the `_flashMessagesService.show()` return an Observable.

In the _flashMessageService, something like this:

```
myObserver : Observer<any>

function show(){
  // do stuff
  return Observable.create(observer =>{ 
     this.myObserver =observer;
  });
}
```

When you're ready to resolve the Observable, you can do:

```
this.myObserver.next('Possibly some value here');  
this.myObserver.complete();
```

In your invoking code

```
 this._flashMessagesService.show()
     .subscribe(result=> { top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard'});}
```

I have been working on something similar.

An alternate approach, perhaps simpler is to just use `Observable.timer` in your main component:

```
Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(result=> { top.location.href = 'admin/dashboard'});
```

I prefer the first way, because it is contingent on the flashMessage service deciding when the flash message goes away, not on a hard coded time value.

Comment: I am new to Angular2. Could you explain it a bit elaborately? I am unaware with the usage of Observable.

Comment: @Saswat Observables are like more advanced promises. It is an asynchronous way to return data.  They are not unique to Angular, but are part of the RXJS library. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ Angular uses them under the hood for their HTTP Services for example. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials on them.

Comment: ok Sir. I will checkout out Observables. Thanks for suggestion :)